# Which Java version can do Robotic?

Tags: java

Which version of JAVA can do robotic act for moving hardware?
Like open and closing gate, make robot, shutdown electricity.

Comment: I think that this is more library dependent than JVM dependent. Since you would of necessity need to use a 3rd party library to achieve this, and the requirements of each library would differ, this begs the question: What are your current library JVM requirements?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels At now i still learning JAVA SE, everybody said it is the basic. Frankly now i wondering, after i can SE, what version i should learn next to be able do Robotic programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, any version.  In practice, it depends on how you intend to interact with the hardware.

Comment: Is that mean, every hardware has some kind of API and java can interact with that API?

Comment: No.  That's not what I mean.  I mean, that it depends on the choices you make in interacting with the hardware from Java.  That presupposes that you actually have a basic understanding about how you are going to do it.  But until you have that basic understanding, details such as which version of Java to use are moot.  Hint: this is WAAAYYYY beyond the basics of Java SE.